# The above program has no package name. In which package the source file of the above program is stored?

Tags: java

The sourcecode is here.
As you see the code it dosen't have any package.

```
public class Welcome1
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Welcome to Java Programming!");
  }
}
```

Comment: No package means no package.

Comment: can u show the project structure ?

Comment: By default your files goes in the default package , which is not a good practice as you can not import files in default package anywhere else.

Comment: #Fatema Sagar   i'd like to show u the all project structure, but that code is all code, and all structure....